# Red Hat Enterprise v8.6 - Air gapped updates from an internet connected RHEL box

Tags: linux, security, redhat, yum

Firstly, hi to everyone as this is my first post.

I am not a Linux expert so could I please ask that if anyone kindly responds to this question that it is in a way that a newbie like me can understand the suggestions.

Scenario:

We have an internet connected RHEL box (v8.6) that we had planned to use to bring down all the RHEL security updates.

We also have many air gapped RHEL servers that we want to update from the downloads on the internet connected RHEL server.

Each RHEL server zone that is air gapped has its own YUM server to provide the updates to all the airgapped servers in that location.

Problem:
To put it bluntly we can't work out how to bring the RHEL security updates down on the internet machine as it continually keeps saying they are all skipped as already downloaed.

We are using the reposync command to bring down the Application and OS security patches that are Critical and Important.

I've looked online and am so confused as to how this task can be achieved, I've seen suggestions that each RPM needs downloading manually (this can't be right!), also mention of an app called Satellite?

My only experience with Linux is Ubuntu which is so much easier to update.

Currently there is a gap in the RHEL space for expertise.

If anyone can help here to make it the simplest way possible to keep 8.6 (and later versions) update to date with the monthly RHEL Security releases.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there no easy way of doing this?

Comment: Does [Is it possible to download RPM files in Fedora (RHEL8) for offline usage?](https://superuser.com/a/1245595/754490) provide some insight?

Comment: So something like `dnf updateinfo list --security` and `dnf download kernel* --security --downloaddir=.`?